# Scala parenthesis semantics

Tags: scala

When appending values to a MAP, why does Scala require the additional parenthesis-block to make this statement work?

Does NOT compile:

```
vmap += (item.getName(), item.getString()) // compiler output: "found: String"
```

However, this Does compile:

```
vmap += ((item.getName(), item.getString())) // note the second set of enclosures
```

TIA

EDIT: vmap is defined as

```
val vmap = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
```

**Epilogue:**
At the time of this edit there are posts detailing two possible explanations, both of which appear to contain elements of truth to them. Which one is actually Correct? I couldn't say with any degree of certainty...I'm just a guy who's still learning the language. That being said, I have changed the answer selection based upon the *feeling* that the one answer is (at least to some extent) encompassed within the other - so I've opted for the larger picture, as I think it will provide a broader meaning for someone else in search of an answer. Ironically, I was trying to get a better understanding of how to flatten out some of the little nuances of the language, and what I've come to realize is there are more of those than I had suspected. I'm not saying that's a bad thing - in fact (IMO) it's to be expected from *any* language that is as flexible and complex - but it sure does make a guy miss the black/white world of Assembly from time-to-time...

To draw this to an end, a couple observations:
1) the selected answer contains a link to a website full of Scala brain-benders (Which I found extremely helpful in trying to understand some of the aforementioned quarks in the language.) Highly recommended.
2) I did come across another interesting twist - whereas the single-parenthesis (example above) does not work, change it the following and it works just fine...

```
vmap += ("foo" -> "bar")
```

Which probably has something to do with matching method/function signatures, but that is just a guess on my part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accepted answer is actually wrong.

The reason you don't get tupling for Map.+= is that the method is overloaded with a second method that takes two or more args.

The compiler will only try tupling if the number of args is wrong. But if you give it two args, and there's a method that takes two, that's what it chooses, even if it fails to type check.

It doesn't start trying all possible combinations until something works because that would be fraught with obscurity.  (Cf implicits.)

```
scala> def f(p: Pair[String, Int]) = { val (s,i) = p; s.toInt + i }
f: (p: Pair[String,Int])Int

scala> f("2",3)  // ok to tuple
res0: Int = 5

scala> trait F { def +=(p: Pair[String, Int]) = f(p) }
defined trait F

scala> val foo = new F {}
foo: F = $anon$1@6bc77f62

scala> foo += ("2",3)  // ok to tuple
res1: Int = 5

scala> trait G { def +=(p: Pair[String, Int]) = f(p); def +=(p:(String,Int),q:(String,Int),r:(String,Int)*) = f(p)+f(q)+(r map f).sum }
defined trait G

scala> val goo = new G {}
goo: G = $anon$1@183aeac3

scala> goo += ("2",3)    // sorry
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("2")
 required: (String, Int)
              goo += ("2",3)
                      ^

scala> goo += (("2",3),("4",5),("6",7))
res3: Int = 27
```

I'd be remiss not to mention your friend and mine, -Xlint, which will warn about untoward arg adaptations:

```
apm@mara:~/tmp$ skala -Xlint
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-20130811-132927-95a4d6e987 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def f(p: Pair[String, Int]) = { val (s,i) = p; s.toInt + i }
f: (p: Pair[String,Int])Int

scala> f("2",3)
<console>:9: warning: Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.
        signature: f(p: Pair[String,Int]): Int
  given arguments: "2", 3
 after adaptation: f(("2", 3): (String, Int))
              f("2",3)
               ^
res0: Int = 5

scala> List(1).toSet()
<console>:8: warning: Adapting argument list by inserting (): this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: GenSetLike.apply(elem: A): Boolean
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: GenSetLike((): Unit)
              List(1).toSet()
                           ^
res3: Boolean = false
```

On the perils of adaptation, see [the Adaptive Reasoning puzzler](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-036) and [this new one that is pretty common](http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-040) because we learn that the presence or absence of parens is largely a matter of style, and when parens really matter, using them wrong results in a type error.

Adapting a tuple in the presence of overloading:

```
scala> class Foo {
     | def f[A](a: A) = 1    // A can be (Int,Int,Int)
     | def f[A](a: A, a2: A) = 2
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> val foo = new Foo
foo: Foo = Foo@2645d22d

scala> foo.f(0,0,0)
<console>:10: warning: Adapting argument list by creating a 3-tuple: this may not be what you want.
        signature: Foo.f[A](a: A): Int
  given arguments: 0, 0, 0
 after adaptation: Foo.f((0, 0, 0): (Int, Int, Int))
              foo.f(0,0,0)
                   ^
res9: Int = 1
```

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding the heart of matter (keeping in mind I'm still relatively new to Scala)...I think what you're showing with f (and foo) is that due to them not having multiple method signatures (ig, overloaded), the compiler has the latitude (and will) infer a tuple while using just a single parenthesis. However, because g (and thus goo) has multiple signatures (and hence ambiguity towards a best match), the compiler will drop the possibility of false inference - and thus the second parenthesis is required as it effectively acts as a tuple literal-izer. Is that accurate?

Comment: Almost. Inferring a tuple is called adapting the arg, see the edit showing that -Xlint will tell you when it happens. Overload resolution is before that. In this case, there is only one method that can be applied to two args, so there is no ambiguity per se (except in our heads). People have called it The Evil Overload.  Not all overloads are created equal; this one is pretty benign. Some badly designed overloads (or inherited from Java) make you say, I asked for f1 and got f2, that has to be a compiler bug.

Comment: Added an example of tupling where tupling is required for application, a bit tricky since inference is taking A as Tuple3.

Comment: I'm wading through your examples and will follow up shortly. In meantime, could me you tell me what "skala" is?  (It looks like it symlink to the scala/java snapshots, but I want to make sure I'm not missing out on some super-duper dev tool!)

Comment: Question/Answer selection modified. Thanks for the info (and website link.) -cheers

Answer (score 4):

Because the `Map +=` method takes a `Tuple2[A, B]` as parameter.

You have to mark the `Tuple2[A, B]` with surrounding parentheses, otherwise the compiler won't infer the type to `Tuple2`.

A `Tuple2` is a simple pair A -> B.

```
val x = (5, 7); // the type is inferred to Tuple2[Int, Int];
```

A `Map` iteration makes this even more obvious:

```
map.foreach { case (key, value) => ...};

(key, value)// is a Tuple2
```

The first set of enclosing parentheses are treated as fruitless/skip-able by the compiler.
The second set of enclosing parentheses creates the needed `Tuple2`.

```
val x = (item.getName(), item.getString());//Tuple2[String, String]
vmap += x; // THIS COMPILES

vmap += (item.getName(), item.getString())// is identical to 
vmap += item.getName(), item.getString() // now it thinks you are adding a String, the result of item.getName()

vmap += (  (item.getName(), item.getString())   )// skips the first set, sees the Tuple, compiles.
```

From the SLS:

Postfix operators have lower precedence than infix operators,
so foo bar baz = foo.bar(baz)

In this case: `vmap += (item.getName(), item.getString()); = vmap.+=(item.getName());`

Comment: I probably should have been more clear in my question: what I'm particularly trying to understand is why your first example is inferred as a Tuple, whereas as my first example is inferred as a simple String?

Comment: I know this is pedantic question, but then how/when does the Scala compiler differentiate? For example, building upon your example, why did (5, 7) not require the second parenthesis to be inferred as a tuple2?

Comment: Ignore comment - it was made before I saw the revision to your answer. Thanks for taking the time to clarify.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that boils down to a difference in how Scala infers assignments compared to parameters?

Comment: The first set of parens is considered to just be the parens around an argument list.  Consider this.  `object X { def f( x:Int, y:Int ) = x+y }` then `X f (3,4)` -- if (3,4) were taken to be a tuple, that wouldn't work.

Comment: I really don't get the bit at the end about postfix. This is infix, and with infix it will also try tupling.  It's true that Map.+= takes a pair, but the rest isn't actually true.  Now you have to contact those four upvoters and disabuse them.